# Simple ada program producing erroneous blank lines using get_line() and put_line()

Tags: stdin, ada

I've been having this issue in a larger program, so I made a new ada program to test it and I get the same thing.

I have a text file (Unix line endings) as so:

```
000_1000_0010_1001
100_0000_0010_1001
100_1000_0000_1001
100_1000_0010_0001
100_1000_0010_1001
000_0000_0011_0011
100_1000_0100
000_0000_0110
111_1111_1111
011_1111_1111
000_0000_0110
```

What I want to do with it is simple, put each line in a string and then just print it right back out.

this is my code:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Read is
   input: String(1..18);
   len: Natural;
begin
   while not End_Of_File loop
      Get_Line(input, len);
      Put_Line(input(1..len));
   end loop;

end Read;
```

Easy right? it takes in each line with get_line, saves it to "input" variable, and then prints out whatever amount of it was read in (using the length returned from get_line().

Unfortunately, I get a bunch of blank lines when I run this code:

```
gnatmake read read.adb
read < input.txt
```

```
000_1000_0010_1001

100_0000_0010_1001

100_1000_0000_1001

100_1000_0010_0001

100_1000_0010_1001

000_0000_0011_0011

100_1000_0100
000_0000_0110
111_1111_1111
011_1111_1111
000_0000_0110
```

I have gone through and made sure I dont have any weird line ending characters in my input file or anything like that (I just typed them out in vim).

This is messing up my program, because i have to account for these erroneous empty lines.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `input` variable can hold 18 characters, and `Get_Line` knows this, so when your input line is more than 18 characters long, it will read only 18 characters. It will then proceed to read the same line until either another 18 characters have been read, or the end of line has been reached. In your case, the input line is *exactly* 18 characters long (not counting the end of line), which just looks weird when the end of line is reached with no characters read into the `input` variable (`len` returns 0)...

You can either increase the length of your `input` buffer to be bigger than any input you can think of, or let the runtime figure out how long the line is by using the `function Get_Line return String;`:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Read is
begin
   while not End_Of_File loop
      declare
         input : String := Get_Line;
      begin
         Put_Line(input);
      end;
   end loop;
end Read;
```

Comment: Specifically, the ARM says, "Reads successive characters from the specified input file and assigns them to successive characters of the specified string. Reading stops if the end of the string is met. Reading also stops if the end of the line is met before meeting the end of the string; in this case Skip_Line is (in effect) called with a spacing of 1." [ARM A.10.7(19) at http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-7.html].  This is what other people have said in other words, but I thought the ARM reference might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to egilhh answer,

First understand the background: there may be lines of text longer than the string provided, so line read is incomplete and it is required to call `Get_Line` more than one time to read whole line.

To detect this case an application simply check if string is filled full, and read the rest. For this to work, `Get_Line` treats the case of matched lengths as incomplete line, leaving 'rest' of line (0 chars) unread.

So, another solution exist:

```ada
   while not End_Of_File loop
      Get_Line(input, len);
      if len < input'Last then
          Put_Line(input(1..len)); -- whole (or the rest of previous) line read,
      else
          Put(input); -- (non-final) part of long line read, do not go to next
      end if;
   end loop;
```

or

```ada
   while not End_Of_File loop
      Get_Line(input, len);
      Put(input(1..len)); -- do not emit eol yet...
      if len < input'Last then
          New_Line; -- now we know: line is finished
      end if;
   end loop;
```